# My app crashes when I touch save button (in Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to do a Contact Manager but I have one problem: My app crashes when I touch save button for saving my new contact, and I don't know why because Eclipse don't says anything is wrong in my code. I touch the button and the app crashes, but it creates a new database.

```
public class Insertarcontactes extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private EditText mNom;
    private EditText mCognoms;
    private EditText mAdressa;
    private EditText mFixe;
    private EditText mMobil;
    private EditText mEmail;
    private DatabaseManager mDBM;
    protected Cursor mCursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    private Button mguardar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.insertarcontactes);

        mDBM = new DatabaseManager();
        mDBM.openDB(this);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mNom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom);
        mCognoms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cognoms);
        mAdressa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adressa);
        mFixe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefonfix);
        mMobil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefonmobil);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mguardar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.guardar);
    }

        public void guardalo(View v) {

                if(!mNom.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                mDBM.insertarContacto(
                        mNom.getText().toString(), 
                        mCognoms.getText().toString(),  
                        mAdressa.getText().toString(), 
                        mFixe.getText().toString(),  
                        mMobil.getText().toString(), 
                        mEmail.getText().toString()
                        );

                mNom.setText("");
                mCognoms.setText("");
                mAdressa.setText("");
                mFixe.setText("");
                mMobil.setText("");
                mEmail.setText("");

                mCursor.requery();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Intent vesalallista = new Intent(this, Llistacontactes.class);
                startActivity(vesalallista);

                }   
            }





        public void tornaenrere(View v){
            Intent tornaenrere = new Intent(this, Menuprincipal.class);
            startActivity(tornaenrere);
        }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()  {
        mDBM.closeDB();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Either don't touch the save button, or post the code with error logs so we can solve it out :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, your question is not clear for us, so we may be unable to provide you any helpful advice. So I would suggest you to read  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to ask question in the form that will ensure your getting help without infinite amount of downvotes

Comment: I would like to advise you to use Android Studio, as support for Eclipse + ADT is discontinued. Next, when asking such a question on StackOverflow, people expect more details, to be able to answer the question. For instance, include the relevant code and any related message that was spit out in the LogCat.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7ApHBjYw8YrfmhyM3NjdGVsYVc5ZlZPS3pZWFI0bElhRjItME5pY2prd2hzdnNRUHBxMDQ&usp=sharing
Here is my app code! It doesn't work but don't have code errors

Comment: @DavidMartínez, can you please upload the relevant code in **question** with error log ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_QXZZT7N5NIrxbUlySjdBMVjBqg4z_036rg_06TsOys/edit?usp=sharing

it crashes when I click the button "guardalo"

Comment: @DavidMartínez, See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31939307/3330969) please. You see, how this person has post code inside the question.  There is a `edit` link below your question, click on it & post your code inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your android manifest file and add write contacts permission

Answer (score 0):

Your `mCursor` is un-initialized, and you are calling its requery() method `mCursor.requery();` in guardalo() method.  Hence it should be giving you `NullPointerException`

You need to initialize this `mCursor` object in `onCreate()` method.